# sharepoint 2013 newsfeed permissions

Tags: permissions, newsfeed

Is there any way to stop users from posting messages to #everyone in newsfeed and allow only to view.

Please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With a little permissions tweak Newsfeed can be made read-only.

Un-check NewsFeed participation in Edit permissions page to stop posting messages.

Here you can find more information:
http://www.n8d.at/blog/allow-users-with-view-permission-add-entries-to-the-newsfeed/